# react native set defaultNavigationOptions to multiple stacknavigations at once

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have a tablayout of which each tab is a stack navigator. each stacknavigator needs to have the same defaultStackNavigationOptions.

Is there a way to set the default options to a group of navigators (I.E. `(HomeStack, SubjectStack, ...).defaultNavigationOptions`)?

**EDIT**:
 Quick edit for clarrification. My current code is this:

```
const homeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Details: DetailsPage,
},
{
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: constants.color.primary },
    headerTitleStyle: { color: "white" },
  }
});
const subjectStack = createStackNavigator({
  Subject: SubjectScreen,
  News: NewsPage,
},
{
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: constants.color.primary },
    headerTitleStyle: { color: "white" },
  }
});
//...
```

These are loaded into a tablayout:

```
export const HomeTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
        screen: homeStack,
    },
    Subject: { 
        screen: subjectStack,
    },
    //...
  }
);
```

I would love to set defaultStackNavigation on every StackNavigator at once, instead of having to copy-paste either this or call a function every time.

If I navigate on the HomeStack on the tablayout, I don't want it to affect the current stack of the Subjectstack on the subject tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sort of found a solution for now. I simply created an object

```
const defaultNavigationOptions = {
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: constants.color.primary },
    headerTitleStyle: { color: "white" },
}
```

and loading it in instead of the regular navigation options, where I can expand on the default nav options with

```
{
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
    ...defaultNavigationOptions,
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: constants.color.secondary },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
 const stackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
      {
        Home: { screen: HomeTab },
        Horse: { screen: HorseTab }
      },
      {
        defaultNavigationOptions: {
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "yellow"
          }
        },
        cardStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "blue"
        }
      }
    );
```

For further reading you can refer to [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html)

In your code you can update like,

```
const stack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Subject: SubjectScreen
},
{
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: constants.color.primary },
    headerTitleStyle: { color: "white" },
  }
});
```

or

```
const HomeTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
        screen: homeStack,
    },
    Subject: { 
        screen: subjectStack,
    },
    //...
  }
);


HomeTabNavigator.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  headerTitle: (
    <Text style={{}}>
      Result
    </Text>
  ),
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "white"
  }
});


export { HomeTabNavigator }
```

Comment: Hey there, I added code for clarification. My page is a tablayout, and there's a seperate stacklayout on each seperate tab.

Comment: What I'm after is having a number of individual stacklayouts, each controlling their own stack. If I tab to another page, and navigate overthere, I want it to not affect the stack on the first page. I'll update the code again in a second.